# Why do the male clones seem more similar to each other than the female clones do?

Tags: plot-explanation, orphan-black

In [Orphan Black](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2234222/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt) there are at least two sets of clones: the females and the males. But the female characters (all played by [Tatiana Maslany](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1137209/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t1)) seem far more different from each other than the males ([Mark Rollins](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0440220/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t10)) do.

Is there a reasonable explanation for the diversity of characteristic of the females compared to the males?

Comment: Old joke:  *"If two guys come to a party dressed the same, they'll likely become best friends.  If two gals arrive at a party dressed the same, they'll instantly hate each other."*  Perhaps that is the philosophy followed by the people responsible for the different looks.

Comment: Spoiler in title!

Answer (score 8):

The male clones grew up in the same environment (military) and were aware that they are clones. The female clones were not aware and were raised by different parents in different locations in the world. The male clones also began interacting with each other at an earlier age than the female clones, and thus had a stronger influence on each other (how siblings tend to be more similar because they learn from each other).

In an debate of nature v. nurture, I think the argument here could be that because the female clones have a diverse nurturing, there is a more diverse characteristic of female clones.

Comment: Nitpick:  At least one of the Leda clones (Rachel) was self-aware.  But I'm pretty sure that she was unique among the female clones in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Graeme Manson (writer and producer):

> The LEDA side has this complex nature-nurture experiment where they're purposely delineated within the experiment and given very different upbringings to see how they'll turn out. Whereas CASTOR, clumped all together, under a military type environment, they were all raised as soldiers with a common purpose. ... Even though there's fractures within that, there's less distinct differences between them.

From Blu-Ray > Featurettes > "Season 3 - Creating the Castor Clones"